# Rails NoMethodError in Posts#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use a view helper in my index view and I keep getting:

```
NoMethodError in Posts#index
undefined method 'content' for #<SpudPost::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fa573bf4c60>
```

I have in my helper the following:

```
module TinyPostsHelper
 def post_truncate(&block)
  truncate(@posts.content,
    length: 500,
    omission: '...') {
      link_to 'Something', post_path(posts.url_name)
      }
    end
```

Then in my controller I have:

```
class TinyPostsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json, :html

  before_action :load_post, except: [:index]
  before_action :new_comment, only: [:post_partial, :post_comments]

  def index
  @return_to = tiny_posts_path
  @posts = TinyPost.ordered.published.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: params[:per_page] || 20)
  @posts = TinyPost::Search.run(@posts, params).result if params[:search]
  end

 def post_partial
  render partial: 'post'
 end

 def show
   if request.xhr?
  render json:
              @post.as_json(only: [:id], methods: [:cover_url],
                            include: { dream_books: { only: :id } }
                            )
else
  new_comment
  render :show
end
end

 def create_comment
   operation = TinyPost::CreateComment.run(comment_params, @post, current_user)
   respond_with operation.result
 end

 def post_comments
  render partial: 'post_comments', locals: { post: @post }
 end

  private

  def load_post
    @post = TinyPost.find_by!(url_name: params[:id])
  end

  def comment_params
   params.require(:dream_post_comment).permit(:content)
  end

  def new_comment
    @comment = DreamPostComment.new
  end
end
```

Then in my view I'm using

```
<%= post_truncate%>
```

I could use string interpolation and the end result is perfectly fine but the problem is that I don't understand why I'm getting the message about content not being a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.content` can't be called on an entire ActiveRecord Relation, only a single post record. You should do something like

```
@posts.each do |post|
    truncate(posts.content,
    length: 500,
    omission: '...') {
       link_to 'Something', post_path(posts.url_name)
    }
end
```

Comment: It works but doesn't for me. I mean it dealt with my issue on ActiveRecord but it's actually displaying everything instead of a single post record. Whereas if I use

Comment: <%= raw (truncate_html posts.content.html_safe, :length =>500, :omission => "...#{link_to 'Continue Reading', post_path(posts.url_name)}") %> no issue

Comment: @Jake if it solved the question posted, please mark as the correct answer.